# How to give condition two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In `Table1` there are three columns `S_Name, Books,  Val`:

```
S_Name     Books   Val
-----------------------
  A         ab     2
  B         aa     3
  A         aa     1
  C         ab     2
  A         ac     3
  D         ac     3
```

Now I want to get the sum of val where B, C student's all books will be counted and for A only ab, and ac books will be counted.

Answer (score 0):

The query will be as

```
SELECT 
    sum(val) 
FROM
    Table1 
WHERE 
    (S_NAME IN ('B','C')) OR (S_name = 'A' AND Books IN ('ab','ac'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    sum(val) 
FROM
    Table1 
WHERE
    (S_NAME IN ('B','C')) OR (S_name = 'A' AND Books IN ('ab','ac'))
```

Comment: missing `from` clause

Comment: Should be `AND Books IN ('ab', 'ac'))` - **round** parenthesis - not square ones!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Python programmer so I get them confused. I had the gist of it. hahahaha